# firestore keyword working in the code in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

Hi guys i am trying write  firestore.instance but it give  error. I can not under stand why this error occur in the below code.

```
  void _fetchMarkersFromDb() {
    // TODO: improve this
    print('_fetchMarkersFromDb() called');

    ***Firestore***.instance.collection('markers').getDocuments().then((docs) async {
      final docLength = docs.documents.length;
      final clients = List(docLength);
      for (int i = 0; i < docLength; i++) {
        clients[i] = docs.documents[i];
      }
      if (!isFirstCycle && isMyMarkerFetched) {
        currentLocation = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
      }
      _populateMarkers(clients);
    });
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtVxs.jpg)

Comment: Did you import Firestore?

Comment: How to import Firestore.

Comment: image attach which show the error

Comment: Hover it and see what it's complaining about exactly.

Comment: now check image

Answer (score 1):

Use `FirebaseFirestore` instead.

Like:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('markers').get().then((value) async {
 var docs = value.docs;
 final docLength = docs.length;
 final clients = List(docLength);
 for (int i = 0; i < docLength; i++) {
    clients[i] = docs[i];
 }
 if (!isFirstCycle && isMyMarkerFetched) {
    currentLocation = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  }
 _populateMarkers(clients);
});
```

To delete a document use:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('markers').doc(documentId).delete()
```

Comment: I already try this but then it give error in .getDocuments( )

Comment: Please share the error at `getDocuments()`

Comment: now check image

Comment: I think you uploaded the wrong image.

Comment: sorry now check

Comment: Hey @AsmaLatif, Check my edit.

Comment: this issue is solve .plz the new image

Comment: Do you want to delete the entire collection?

Comment: no I don't want

Comment: Hey @AsmaLatif, I've added the code for deleting.

Comment: Kindly accept and upvote if it works for you.